# Foundation 6 Wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

I am trying to add some animation to the mobile navigation to drop down slowly rather than have the page jumping. I am using the foundationpress theme. I can't seem to make it work with **data-animate**. This is my code snippet:

```
<div class="title-bar" data-responsive-toggle="site-navigation">
        <button class="menu-icon" data-toggle="panel" type="button" data-toggle="mobile-menu"></button>
        <div class="title-bar-title">

            <div class="mini-logo">
            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><img class="mini-logo-img" src="/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/coc-logo.png" alt="Mountain View" style="width:4rem;height:auto;"></a>
            </div>
            <!--<a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a>-->
        </div>
    </div>
```

```
    <!--<nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation nav-area" role="navigation" style="width:100%" >-->
        <div class="top-bar-left">
            <ul class="menu">
                <li class="co-logo-top"></li>
                <!--<li class="home"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></li>-->
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="top-bar-right" >
            <?php foundationpress_top_bar_r(); ?>

            <?php if ( ! get_theme_mod( 'wpt_mobile_menu_layout' ) || get_theme_mod( 'wpt_mobile_menu_layout' ) === 'topbar' ) : ?>
                <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/mobile-top-bar' ); ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not seeing the actual '#mobile-menu' component in your code snippet, so not 100% sure what's happening here, but the thing to be aware of is that you need to have the data-animate attribute on the same element as you have your data-toggler attribute (which in this case is the thing being toggled, or '#mobile-menu').  See the example here: http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/toggler.html#toggle-with-animation

Answer (score 0):

have you tried triggering it with jquery/js? see this thread: https://github.com/olefredrik/FoundationPress/issues/772.

also check that you have added the `data-toggler` attribute to the element